# C++ Copy structure without pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

I want to copy data structure into another one

```
struct times{
    QString name;
    double time1;
    double time2;
    double time3;
};

/..../

times *abc = new times[10];
times *abc2 = new times[10];
```

How can I copy abc into abc2 without copying a pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::copy(abc, abc+10, abc2);
```

although, unless you've got a very good reason for juggling raw pointers, use a friendlier container:

```
std::vector<times> abc(10);
std::vector<times> abc2 = abc;  // copy-initialisation
abc2 = abc;                     // copy-assignment
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that this depends on `QString` being copy constructable.

Comment: @MichaelUrman: Indeed, if the type you wanted to copy weren't copyable, then copying would be impossible. Luckily, [`QString`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html) is.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   abc2[i] = abc[i];
```

or, alternatively

```
std::copy_n(abc, 10, abc2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use a copy constructor in your struct.

```
struct times{
    times(const &A) {
        this->name = A.name;
        this->time1 = A.time1;
        this->time2 = A.time2;
        this->time3 = A.time3;
    }
};
```

Comment: Why would you do that? It does (almost) exactly what the implicit copy constructor would do.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, It is same as assigning char pointer.

```
struct TestStruct
{
int a;
float c;
char b;
};

main()
{
    struct TestStruct *structa = new TestStruct;

    structa->a = 1121;
    structa->b = 'D';
    structa->c = 12.34;

    struct TestStruct *abc = structa;
    cout<<abc->a;
}
```